# FaceBook app: retrieve list of ids of my application's users

Tags: facebook

can I retrieve it using fql or graph api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time a user comes to your app, his facebook id can be retrieved like this:

```
$facebook = new Facebook($api_key, $secret);
$facebook->require_frame();
$user_id = $facebook->require_login();
echo $user_id;
```

Now the facebook id is stored in the variable `$user_id`. Once you receive an id like that, you should save it in your database and you can get them back from your database any time you like :)

Comment: Is there an [Authorize Callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579717/how-do-i-get-all-the-users-that-have-authorized-my-facebook-app)?