# How do I get all the users that have authorized my Facebook app?

Tags: facebook

There used to be an Authorization Callback, but I only see a [Deauthorization Callback](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#post_remove_callback) now.

So, what's the suggested way to store & get a list of users that have authorized the app?

This answer suggests to [always add a user to the list of app users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932696/facebook-app-retrieve-list-of-ids-of-my-applications-users/2932730#2932730).

Is that the best way?

Answer (score 2):

I guess this can be done with the newly introduced [insights](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/) feature, as mentioned in page the [FQL Insights Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights#Metrics) has a full list of metrics, and I guess what you need is:

- application_installed_users
  Available Periods: lifetime
  Total installations of your application or connections to your Connect application

Comment: I think that just returns the total count, not all the user ids that have installed the application, but good to know. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't try it so I can't judge what could be the result of the query (I don't OWN an application with 30+ connections), would appreciate if you post what it returns :-)