# How do I get my Facebook app's authorized users with App access token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.3

I need to access my active app users and their permissions. I've got my app token, but I don't know how to get my users and their permissions.

At Graph API Explorer I'm requesting (with my app token) `MY_APP_ID/insights` but it just provides general data.

If I request `MY_APP_ID` path itself it just returns a brief description of my app and some data.

I need to access an endpoint like `MY_APP_ID/users` (tried that one, it doesn't exist) and it should return my app's users. It is the data that I technically have access to, so I should be able to browse it.

I've seen [How do I get all the users that have authorized my Facebook app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579717/how-do-i-get-all-the-users-that-have-authorized-my-facebook-app) which links to an FQL table but FQL is deprecated and not allowed after Graph API 2.0 and my app is created after 2.1 is released, therefore I can't use FQL.

I've also found (after deep digging into Facebook's docs) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/app/app_insights but again, I couldn't find a way to get that specific data.

How can I get my app users?

To be specific, I need something like this:

`GET /APP_ID/users?since=24hoursago`

```
Response:
[{
  uid: 123456789,
  permissions: basic_info, email, user_friends,
  name: James Williams,
  date: 2015-06-13T00:11:22
},
{
  uid: 567892345,
  permissions: basic_info, email, user_friends,
  name: Adam Smith,
  date: 2015-06-13T00:11:22
},
{
  uid: 8765431929,
  permissions: basic_info, email, user_friends,
  name: Kurt Adams,
  date: 2015-06-13T00:11:22
}]
```

Name and permissions are mandatory and login date would be extremely helpful.

Comment: There is no endpoint that provides a list of app users. If you need any such data, you’ll need to collect it when the individual user logs in to your app.

Comment: @CBroe yes but there has been a tech difficulty server-side that's why I need it at the first place. otherwise, I am collecting all the data.

Comment: Doesn’t matter, it is simply **not available** via API.