# Facebook App Users List

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am fairly new to the Facebook APIs. I want to get a list of my friends who have also installed my app. (The idea being you can then start a game with them).

This gives a list of my friends:

```js
FB.api('/me/friends', ...
```

This gives my app info:

```js
FB.api('/myappid', ...
```

What I want is "my friends who also have this app installed"

I thought it might be this:

```js
FB.api('/myappid/accounts', ...
```

I was hoping that would at least give me my Developers, Administrators or Testers, but no such luck.
    http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/
    http://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/

My feeling is perhaps I have to use FQL to construst a query that says something like

```sql
(psuedocode)
SELECT
FROM my_friends
WHERE uid IN (
    SELECT uid
    FROM app_users
    WHERE appid = myappid
)
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Note, I have seen this post:
[FaceBook app: retrieve list of ids of my application's users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932696/facebook-app-retrieve-list-of-ids-of-my-applications-users)

I am keeping a local list of Facebook User's IDs that belong to my site, and I am actually able to achieve my goal by doing the following, but I am sure there must be a better way:

```php
$facebookFriendIds = array();
$friends = $this->facebook->api('/me/friends');
foreach ($friends['data'] as $friend) {
    $facebookFriendIds[] = $friend['id'];
}

$this->friends = Doctrine_Core::getTable('User')->createQuery()
    ->whereIn('fb_user_id', $facebookFriendIds)
    ->execute();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is I believe the FQL query

`$facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => "SELECT uid FROM user WHERE is_app_user = '1' AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = '" . $user_id . "');"));`

(I use java and JS APIs so the syntax may not be exactly correct)

The documentation for the user and friend queries are here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend/

Answer (score 1):

Use this query in JS

```
function getAppFriends()
{

    var fql = "SELECT uid, name, pic_square, is_app_user 
               FROM user 
               WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) 
               OR uid IN(SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=me()) 
               ORDER BY  name";

    var query = FB.Data.query(fql);

    query.wait(function(responseFromFb){

       if(responseFromFb!=null){

           // Read the responseFromFb and check for 
           // is_app_user = true and list them out the way 
           // you want to.

       }

    });// anonymus function closes here
} //function ends here
```