# Get facebook's friends by name

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, friend

I need to obtain my friends of facebook (who are using my app).

Example: I pass a parameter like "Jo" to Graph API, the Facebook must return to me all Friends like Jose, Jon, xxJoxx, etc.

I dont know if that its possible.

Thanks!

Comment: you want a list of users of your app?

Comment: @RobertMoskal Yes!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook App Users List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623035/facebook-app-users-list). I think you'll find that answers your question.

Comment: @RobertMoskal Sorry but don't, that post use fql, but it's deprecated I am using API 2.5 and SDK Javascript

Comment: Just get all friends that are using your app and filter yourself

Comment: @WizKid Thanks!! Sadly it's the only way apparently

Answer (score 0):

You can get all friends with `/me/friends` and implement your own code with autocomplete to do that. There is also the Search API, but you would need to do a LOT of API calls for an autocomplete functionality: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search

...also, you don´t just get friends with the Search API.